# In springframe, annotations can be inherited?

Tags: spring, annotations

I have a problem. In the previous version, I remember that the annotations cannot be inherited, but in the latest version, the annotations can be inherited. Is this a new feature?
For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/user-facade")
public interface AdminUserFacade {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/user/permission")
    Result<List<PermissionDTO>> findPermissionByUserName(@RequestParam("userName") 
    String userName);
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class AdminUserFacadeImpl implements AdminUserFacade {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Override
    public Result<List<PermissionDTO>> findPermissionByUserName(String userName) {
        return new Result<>(adminService.findPermissionByUserName(userName));
    }
}
```

In the previous version,The override method findPermissionByUserName must add the annotation @RequestParam,If not add, Can't get the value of userName.

Answer (score 0):

He may be updated in November 2017, please see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20764) for related information.